# Common words check loop doesn't work

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to make a program that reads two file and gives me the common word as 2-gram. I wrote the below code.

> here is the node

```
   struct node {
    char *string;
    struct node *next;
};
```

> here is the check loop

```
struct node *sw1, *sw2, *sw1_head;

//first 1 and first2 is the head of linked lists that holds text's each word seperatly. i created before.

first1 = first1_head; // _ head is the same as first1 and first2
first2 = first2_head;

//sw1 and sw2 are the pointers that holds always second words.
sw2 = first2->next;
sw1 = first1->next;
sw1_head = sw1;

//these chars are used to concat two words
char destination1[50];
char destination2[50];

while(sw2 != NULL){

        strcpy(destination2,first2->string);
        strcat(destination2,sw2->string);

        while(sw1 != NULL){

        strcpy(destination1,first1->string);
        strcat(destination1,sw1->string);
    //  printf("%s\n", destination1);
        if(strcmp(destination2, destination1) == 0) {

            insert(&matched2, destination1);//matched holds common words

            }

            sw1 = sw1->next;        
            first1 = first1->next;

        }

        sw1 = sw1_head;//sets both sw1 and first1 to their past positions.
        first1 = first1_head;
        sw2 = sw2->next;
        first2 = first2->next;
    }
```

When i tried to print the **matched2** linkedlist. It gives me 21 **adocument** which is the last two words of first file which is not even common. I think there is something wrong in **strcmp function**.

I asked a similar question before but they are not same.

Here is how i print matched2 linked-list.

```
while(matched2 != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", matched2->string);
    matched2 = matched2->next;
}
```

here is the `insert` method

```
void insert(struct node **new_node, char* new_data){

/* allocate node */
struct node *ptr1 =(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));      
/* put in the data  */
ptr1->string  = new_data;
ptr1->next =  NULL;
if(new_node == NULL){
*new_node = ptr1; return;
}
ptr1->next = *new_node;
*new_node = ptr1;
```

Comment: You really must initialize your string buffers or they'll be full of garbage data.

Comment: @tadman what values shoud i appoint to them?

Comment: You could always zero it out with `memset` or `bzero` depending on your preferences. Initializing as a zero byte is also an option. C strings are NULL terminated, so you need to terminate them before using any of the standard string functions.

Comment: What's missing here is how you're using this code to generate that problem.  Is this code inside a function that's not shown? Is this the `main()` function? There's a lot of context that's absent and leading to speculation.

Comment: @this all happens in `main()` function. I just don't want to write to avoid a mess up.

Comment: It's not a mess if it adds context. If we can copy your code, compile it and reproduce the problem without having to do any work you've written a good question. If we need to fuss around and add lots of things that aren't obvious it makes for a lot of duplicated and unnecessary work.

Comment: there are only first1 and first2 linked-lists above. I don't know if it's add anything beneficial.

Comment: It's not clear how you're getting the "adocument" result because the way that code's exercised is not shown. The "document" text does not appear in your code, only in your description of the bug.

Comment: **adocument** is the last two words of first file that i want to compare with another.

Comment: You'll need to show how this code is used. A self-contained example is best. External file dependencies are annoying.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Where is `insert` function defined?

Comment: @rslemos i added

Comment: Please post an [mcve] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `insert` function to:

```
void insert(struct node **new_node, char* new_data){

/* allocate node */
struct node *ptr1 =(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));      
/* put in the data  */
ptr1->string  = strdup(new_data);
ptr1->next =  NULL;
if(new_node == NULL){
*new_node = ptr1; return;
}
ptr1->next = *new_node;
*new_node = ptr1;
```

The only change is that the line `ptr1->string  = new_data` should `strdup` the `new_data`.

If you look closely, `insert` is invoked with `destination1`, which is a fixed buffer. So if you do not copy its content each time you create a new node, every node will end pointing to the very same buffer, which will contain the last two words.

**Also**

That part

```
if(new_node == NULL){
*new_node = ptr1; return;
}
```

is probably dead code, that is, `new_node` is never NULL perhaps because your list head is pre-initialized (we will never know for sure if you do not post your complete code).

If this is not dead code (you can check it by printf'ing right inside the `if`), then there is a bug lurking here, since when `new_node` is `NULL`, then `*new_node` dereferences NULL, which should trigger SIGSEGV.

Comment: I forgot to ask. My compiler doesn't accept this `ptr1->string  = strcpy(new_data);`

Comment: Sorry, I really meant `strdup`.

Comment: it's ok. I've found another solution. I changed the char pointer in struct with char array. I just needed to rearrange somethings and it work. Anyway thanks for your help attention.

Comment: It is fine, provided that you `strcpy` data into the `char[]` member.